# Non-latin(Multi-Language) file names passing to multipart API in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, multipartform-data

> trying to upload the file from iPhone iCloud to the multipart API.
>   When the file name is in English text it shows well after uploading but I do have the file name in another language than English then it is wrong.

**In the below image the file name is in Chinese "樣品.pdf" but when I upload that then in response I do get the text as "??.pdf"**

[image: file name in chinese]

Backend API already handled this conversion since when I do upload the file from Android it works.

Also when I send in text from textfiled then it shows correctly what should I do for the String?

//`Code from uploading API Call`

```
myRequestData.append("\(MPboundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                // set upload image, name is the key of image
                myRequestData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(mediaObj!.key)\"; filename=\"\(mediaObj!.fileName)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                myRequestData.append("Content-Type: \(mediaObj!.mimeType)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                myRequestData.append(mediaObj!.data!)
                myRequestData.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

Comment: are you storing the file to app's document folder, before sending it to the server? if yes it is stored in the document directory properly? and though it is working for android, you can ask the backend dev to check what raw value he/she is getting before storing it to db

Comment: Yes, i am storing that. And i have asked the back-end guy he want me to send that file name using non-latin format .. how m i supposed to do that?

Comment: Ask him to change the db file name field collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci it will be fixed, otherwise you have to encode it while sending the file and and decode it during showing it on your app

Comment: that worked.. will that affect old data? and will support for all languages?

Comment: there will be no issue with old data, and yes it will support for all language. I am adding the above comment as answer, if you like please upvote and accept it.

Comment: Sure thanks. And upvote my question if i am asked it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the db `filename` field `collation` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` it will be fixed, otherwise you have to encode it while sending the `filename` and decode it during showing it on your app.